# Conditional Distribution Multivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, multivariate-normal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$, be jointly distributed according to a multivariate normal distribution.

$[X_1, X_2, X_3]^T\sim N(\mu=[0,0,0]^T , \Sigma = [[5,0,0],[0,2,1], 0,1,3]])$

$U = X_1 + 2X_2$ and $V = X_2 – X_3$

How to find the conditional distribution of $U$ given that $V = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Both $U$ and $V$ are jointly normal RVs because this is a linear transformation over jointly normal RVs. So, by finding the mean, variance and covariance of these RVs you'll find the joint distribution of $U,V$.

Then, the conditional of one over another is also normal. You can find the related conditional using the joint distribution of $U,V$ as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#/Conditional_distributions).

Comment: How can I find the covariance between U and V?

Comment: just subtitute their definitions, you’ll have an expression in terms of X’s. Then, use distributive property of covariance and write it in terms of covariances between X’s.